# convert timestamp into PST in cakephp and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am newbie to cakephp and want to convert the  unix time in PST in both cakephp and jquery.
please let me know were default timezone so that i don't have to mention it again n again?

```
 date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
```

I have tried converting it by following method:-

```
$timestamp='1397147133';    
date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");
echo $str=date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$timestamp); die;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Cakephp, you can set default timezone on `core.php` under Config folder.
As `App/Config/core.php`

set `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`
to `date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles");`

Comment: will it automatically convert the date in PST? both in cake and jquery?

Comment: You're going to want to use CakeTime to display your time fields, and then yes, it will.

Comment: In database i am saving the timestamp. and i have changed the
set date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); to date_default_timezone_set("America/Los_Angeles"); but it reflects the same datetime

Comment: Well @Piya Sharma, I can remember you asked a similar question earlier and can recall that you saved your datetime as string. You should understand the different between how mysql store dates... Change your column to DATETIME OR TIMESTAMP. Why are you saving your datetime as UNIX-TIMESTAMP to a varchar column?

Comment: i cannot change the column to datetime.

Comment: Whats that mean? You don't wish to change or you haven't that permission to change or you don't know how to change?

Comment: @PiyaSharma: If you answer Fazal's question, we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by editing the default timezone setting in core.php file in cakephp.

You will find this file in the location  "app/config/core.php".

```
/**
 * Uncomment this line and correct your server timezone to fix
 * any date & time related errors.
 */

//date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Replace 'UTC' with your favourite timezone and uncomment above line.

For jQuery you can use plugins like: [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)